# How to get only one record in subquery for each record's max result

Tags: mysql, report

I have a user - course - exam database.

Table structures:

### user table structure

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|                    user                    |
+--------------------------------------------+
| user_id | fullname     | email             |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+
| 1       | Test User 01 | test01@domain.com |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+
| 2       | Test User 02 | test02@domain.com |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+
| 3       | Test User 03 | test03@domain.com |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+
| 4       | Test User 04 | test04@domain.com |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+
```

### course table structure

```
+-----------------------+
|         course        |
+-----------------------+
| course_id | title     |
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | Course 01 |
+-----------+-----------+
| 2         | Course 02 |
+-----------+-----------+
| 3         | Course 03 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

### course_exam table structure (course can have one or more exam)

```
+----------------------------+
|         course_exam        |
+----------------------------+
| course_exam_id | course_id |
+----------------+-----------+
| 1              | 1         |
+----------------+-----------+
| 2              | 1         |
+----------------+-----------+
| 3              | 2         |
+----------------+-----------+
| 4              | 3         |
+----------------+-----------+
| 5              | 2         |
+----------------+-----------+
```

### user_course_exam table structure (users can join one or more exam)

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                user_course_exam                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_course_exam_id | course_exam_id | user_id | right_answer_total | wrong_answer_total | blank_answer_total |
+---------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 1                   | 1              | 1       | 2                  | 3                  | 0                  |
+---------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 2                   | 1              | 1       | 4                  | 1                  | 0                  |
+---------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 3                   | 2              | 1       | 5                  | 0                  | 0                  |
+---------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 4                   | 1              | 1       | 3                  | 1                  | 1                  |
+---------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 5                   | 3              | 1       | 4                  | 0                  | 1                  |
+---------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I should prepare a report like below:

- user_id
- fullname
- email
- completed_course_total (course total having completed exams by user)
- remaining_course_total
- right_answer_total (Max right answer for best scored exam. Only one result should fetch for each course)

### Expected report result

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_id | fullname     | email             | completed_course_total | remaining_course_total | right_answer_total |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
| 1       | Test User 01 | test01@domain.com | 2                      | 1                      | 13                 |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
| 2       | Test User 02 | test02@domain.com | 0                      | 3                      | 0                  |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
| 3       | Test User 03 | test03@domain.com | 0                      | 3                      | 0                  |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
| 4       | Test User 04 | test04@domain.com | 0                      | 3                      | 0                  |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
```

This is my query, but right answer result returns all of exams. **I want get only sum of max right answer total for each courses.**

Please also consider these cases:

- A course can have more than one exams.
- A user can join more than one course_exam.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  `user`.user_id,
    (   
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`user_course_exam`.`course_exam_id`)) FROM `user_course_exam` 
            INNER JOIN `course_exam` ON (`course_exam`.`course_exam_id` = `user_course_exam`.`course_exam_id`)
        WHERE `user_course_exam`.`user_id` = `user`.`user_id` && `course_exam`.course_id IN (
                SELECT course_id FROM course_exam 
                WHERE status = '1' 
                GROUP BY `course_exam`.`course_id`
            )
    ) AS completed_course,
    (   
        SELECT SUM(`user_course_exam`.`right_answer_total`) FROM `user_course_exam`
            INNER JOIN `course_exam` ON (`course_exam`.`course_exam_id` = `user_course_exam`.`course_exam_id`)
        WHERE `user_course_exam`.`user_id` = `user`.`user_id` && `course_exam`.course_id IN (
                SELECT course_id FROM course_exam
                WHERE status = '1' 
                GROUP BY `course_exam`.`course_id`
            ) ORDER BY `user_course_exam`.`right_answer_total` DESC
    ) AS right_answer
FROM
    `user`
WHERE
    `user`.`user_id` > 0
GROUP BY
    `user`.`user_id`
ORDER BY
    `user`.`user_id` ASC
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

JSFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72ee15/1/0

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) but i suspect the question to be a duplicate and it will be most likely voteclosed.

Comment: I searched for this problem on site but couldn't find such a problem.

Comment: *"I searched for this problem on site but couldn't find such a problem"* Annyhow this question is unclear without example data and expected results so most likely it will be voteclosed to be *"unclear what you are asking"*

Comment: Hello, I added SQLFiddle url to my question. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72ee15/1/0

All I want is, get the max right answer total for each course. In my query, I get all of right answer's total for each course.

Comment: The example data is good but you would need to edit it in your question, but we also need to have expecteds results als we don't want to think how your results should be.. Also when you provide expected results as data table we can verify our query much more easy and also we dont have to "guess". i would suggest using this [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) tool to generate text based ascii tables.

Comment: Hello @RaymondNijland, thank you for you directing me to ask more understandable question. I added tables and expected result table to question.

Comment: why 13 `right_answer_total` if "Test User 01" complete 2 course?

Comment: Because, "Test User 01" completed two different exams of Course 01 and one exam of Course 03. 
Maximum right answer total for "Course 01" 's first exam (course_exam_id: 1): 4 (user_course_exam_id: 2)
Maximum right answer total for "Course 01" 's second exam (course_exam_id: 2): 5 (user_course_exam_id: 3)
Maximum right answer total for "Course 02" 's exam (course_exam_id: 3): 4 (user_course_exam_id: 5)

sum of the right answers: 5 + 4 + 4 = 13

Comment: If I complete only a part of the exam. Is the exam complete or remaining?if it is in 3 parts counts 1,2 or 3?

Comment: It accepted as completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `MAX()` than `SUM()`

```
SELECT DISTINCT `user`.`user_id`,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (`user_course_exam`.`course_exam_id`))
            FROM `user_course_exam`
                     INNER JOIN `course_exam`
                                ON (`course_exam`.`course_exam_id` = `user_course_exam`.`course_exam_id`)
            WHERE `user_course_exam`.`user_id` = `user`.`user_id` && `course_exam`.`course_id` IN (
                SELECT `course_id`
                    FROM `course_exam`
                    GROUP BY `course_exam`.`course_id`
            )
    ) AS `completed_course`,
    (
        SELECT sum(`all_curse`.`max_right_answer`)
            FROM (
                     SELECT MAX(`user_course_exam`.`right_answer_total`) AS `max_right_answer`,
                            `user_course_exam`.`user_id`
                         FROM `user_course_exam`
                                  INNER JOIN `course_exam`
                                             ON `course_exam`.`course_exam_id` = `user_course_exam`.`course_exam_id`
                         WHERE `course_exam`.`status` = 1
                         GROUP BY `course_exam`.`course_id`, `course_exam`.`course_exam_id`
                 ) AS `all_curse`
            WHERE `all_curse`.`user_id` = `user`.`user_id`
    ) AS `right_answer`
FROM `user`
WHERE `user`.`user_id` > 0
GROUP BY `user`.`user_id`
ORDER BY `user`.`user_id`
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

JSFiddle: [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c78060/8)

Comment: Hello, I want get only sum of max right answer total for each courses.